# Indenting base classes and member initialization lists

Tags: vim

The documentation for indenting base classes and member initialization list says (`:help cino-i`):

> ```
> iN      Indent C++ base class declarations and constructor
>         initializations, if they start in a new line (otherwise they
>         are aligned at the right side of the ':').
>         (default 'shiftwidth').
> ```

I use `i2s` in `cinoptions` and `shiftwidth=3`. When I indent the following

```
class Foo : public Bar,
public Baz
{
};
```

I would like it to be

```
class Foo : public Bar,
            public Baz
{
};
```

but I get

```
class Foo : public Bar,
      public Baz
{
};
```

Similarly, when I indent

```
Foo(int x, int y) : x_(x),
y_(y)
{
}
```

I would like to get

```
Foo(int x, int y) : x_(x),
                    y_(y)
{
}
```

but I get

```
Foo(int x, int y) : x_(x),
      y_(y)
{
}
```

I thought the wording `otherwise they are aligned at the right side of the ':'` would do exactly what I want. It seems I am misinterpreting that line.

Is there any way to get the desired indenting?

#### Additional Info

Platform: Windows 10
vim version: 8.1

My settings:

```
  autoindent          fileformat=dos    nolangremap           scrolloff=5         tabstop=3           ttymouse=xterm
  background=dark     filetype=cpp        laststatus=2      noshelltemp           textmode            visualbell
  cindent             helplang=en         mousemodel=popup    shiftwidth=3        textwidth=100       wildmenu
  clipboard=unnamed   hlsearch            nrformats=bin,hex   showcmd             ttimeout          nowrap
  display=truncate    incsearch           ruler               showmatch           ttimeoutlen=100
  expandtab           langnoremap         scroll=24           syntax=cpp          ttyfast
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  cinkeys=0{,0},:,o,O,0#,!<Tab>
  cinoptions=>1s,e0,n0,f0,{0,}0,^0,:s,=s,ps,ts,c3,i2s,+s,(0,u0,)20,*30,gs,hs,W2s
  comments=sr:/*,mb:*,el:*/,://
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  formatoptions=crql
  keymodel=startsel,stopsel
  omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete
  selection=exclusive
  selectmode=mouse,key
  statusline=%f%h%m%r [%{&ff}] (%{strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y",getftime(expand("%:p")))})%=%l,%c%V %P
  suffixesadd=.h,.cc,.C,.cpp,.xml,.scm
  whichwrap=b,s,<,>,[,]
  wildmode=list:longest,longest:full
```

Comment: What did you type into `:help [...]` to get the quoted paragraph? What exactly do you mean by "I use `i2s`"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 `:help cino-i`

Comment: Ah, I'm assuming you are referring to `:help cinoptions-values` and have used `:set cinoptions=i2s`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, that is correct.

Comment: Simply using `:set cino=i2s` gives me the behavior you want. Are you sure Vim has been compiled with the `+cindent` option? You can check with `:echo has('cindent')`.

Comment: @Das_Geek, Yes, it is compiled with `+cindent`. I get `1` as the output of `:echo has('cindent')`

Comment: @Das_Geek, I wonder what other settings could interfere with that.

Comment: @RSahu Actually, I found why it "worked" for me. I didn't type the comma after the first member declaration. `class Foo : public bar\n public baz` indented as you want, but adding the comma after `bar` broke it

Comment: @Das_Geek, I get the same behavior if I don't use `,`. Maybe they are expecting the `,` to be used in the second line, no the first line.

Comment: @RSahu Methinks my magical indenting has nothing to do with the `cino` options, as setting `cindent` to true without configuring options produces the same behavior, and setting `cino=i2s` only changes how much the member declaration is indented *from the start of the line*. I think the `otherwise they are aligned at the right side of the ':'` probably only refers to how these members are typically declared, and this indent option only kicks in when they get put on a new line. Which aligns with your example, as they're indented by 6 spaces, or `i2s` if `shiftwidth=3`.